# Odoo 9 unable to save id from many2one model

Tags: odoo, relationship, one-to-many, odoo-9, many-to-one

I'm currently building a module like a project module which shows Kanban view for model 'test.project' and when I click Kanban view, It shows tree views for model 'test.task' related to 'test.project'.

So I made a code below

```
class Test_project(osv.osv):

    _name = "test.project"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name'),
        'task_ids': fields.one2many('test.task', 'project_id', string='TASK')
    }

class Test_Task(osv.osv):

    _name = 'test.task'
    _columns = {
        'project_id': fields.many2one('test.project', string='Project ID', required=1),
    }
```

When I saved a data for 'test.project', It is saved correctly, But When I saved a data for 'test.task', It shows an error which is

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Cannot get the id.

Comment: in your 'test.task' project_id is required so while creating record for 'test.task' project_id=False so its give this error

Comment: @ADVALAKI Then how do you get project_id while creating a record for 'test.task'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `required=1` on the definition of the `project_id` field. That means that every time you create and save a record you will have to give a value to that fields otherwise you will not be able to save it.

Comment: Then is there a way to get project_id to save on the record? I cannot find a way in the core source.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please be specific

Comment: I'd like to store project_id in a model 'test.task' to use it on a tree view with domain [(project_id=active_id)]. So each test.project record has only test.task records which is many2one related to test.project

Comment: The problem here is that when you create the `test.task` from the `test.project` then the project_id field gets automatically filled and contains the test.project's id. If go and create a task you have to either insert the project id field on the view and assign it yourself or override the create, or write or pass default_project_id on the action that opens the task

Comment: Thanks! I successfully create the module with your advise that pass default_project_id on the action.